# Некорректное отображение интерфейса приложения собранного в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Всем доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с проблемой: собрал приложение в  Visual Studio 2019 (приложение старое, не я его писал), запускаю ехе файл в релизной папке и интерфейс некорректно отображается - отсутствуют надписи в полях меню,  при этом запускаю релизную версию приложения в Visual Studio 2019 всё в норме. Может каких библиотек при сборке не хватает, а в студии они по умолчанию подгружаются? Как решать эту проблему?

[image: Некорректное]
[image: Корректно]

Comment: Добавьте метку языка программирования - это привлечёт больше внимания к вопросу

Comment: ¿Может текущая папка неверно указана?

Comment: Нужно изучать структуру проекта, без этого можно только общие рекомендации дать. Из опыта: скорее всего не подтягиваются ресурсы. Они могут быть как в отдельной библиотеке (dll), так и в файлах конфигурации (ini, xml etc). Строки могут хранится в файлах языковой поддержки. По умолчанию при запуске приложения ресурсы ищутся сначала в рабочем каталоге. При запуске через студию рабочий каталог - это каталог проекта: все работает. Без студии - рабочий каталог - каталог запуска приложения, если там нет нужных файлов, результат будет такой как у вас. Или вообще не стартанет.

Comment: А ведь так и оказалось. В релизной папке не хватало некоторых каталогов и несколько библиотек, которые были в каталоге с решением, как только их скопировал в релиз - всё запустилось корректно. Большое вам спасибо.